# Distributed erlang security how to?

Tags: erlang

I want to have 2 independent erlang nodes that could communicate with each other:

so node **`a@myhost`** will be able to send messages to **`b@myhost`**.

Are there any ways to restrict node **`a@myhost`**, so only a function from  a **secure_module** could be called on **`b@myhost`**?

It should be something like:

```
a@myhost> rpc:call(b@myhost,secure_module,do,[A,B,C]) returns  {ok,Result}
```

and  all other calls

```
a@myhost> rpc:call(b@myhost,Modue,Func,Args)  return {error, Reason}
```

One of the options would be to use `ZeroMQ` library to establish a communication between nodes, but would it be better if it could be done using some standard Erlang functions/modules?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case distributed Erlang is not what you want. Connecting node A to node B makes a single cluster -- one huge, trusted computing environment. You don't want to trust part of this, so you don't want a single cluster.

Instead write a specific network service. Use the network itself as your abstraction layer. The most straightforward way to do this is to establish a stream connection (just boring old `gen_tcp`, or `gen_sctp` or use ssl, or whatever) from A to B.

The socket handling process on A receives messages from whatever parts of node A need to call B -- you write this *exactly* as you would if they were directly connected. Use a normal Erlang messaging style: `Message = {name_of_request, Data}` or similar. The connecting process on A simply does `gen_tcp:send(Socket, term_to_binary(Message))`.

The socket handling process on B shuttles received network messages between the socket and your servicing processes by simply receiving `{tcp, Socket, Bin} -> Servicer ! binary_to_term(Bin)`.

Results of computation go back the other direction through the exact same process using the `term_to_binary`/`binary_to_term` translation again.

Your service processes should be receiving *well defined* messages, and disregarding whatever doesn't make sense (usually just logging the nonsense). So in this way you are not doing a direct RPC (which is unsafe in an untrusted environment) you are only responding to *valid semantics* defined in your (little tiny) messaging protocol. The way the socket handling processes are written is what can abstract this for you and make it feel just as though you are dealing with a trusted environment within distributed Erlang, but actually you have two independent clusters which are limited in what they can request of each other by the definition of your protocol.

Comment: Thanks. This was a "plan B" :) Are there any advantages of using gen_tcp/gen_sctp over say zeroMQ?

Comment: @AntonProkofiev Simplicity. Which, for me at least, is everything. I tend to avoid including external packages until my project demonstrates a need for something specific that will take less time to read/configure/understand than build. In this case your need is *really* simple, and already exists: `term_to_binary`/`binary_to_term`. It is so easy to build network services in Erlang that *most* of the time this is adequate. Abstract the socket behind an Erlang message protocol and you can drop a messaging service in later once you *know* that you need it (advanced routing, for example).