# How To Secure Erlang Cluster Behind Private Subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, erlang

I am testing Erlang and have a few questions related to Security of the Distribution.  (There is a lot of mixed information out there)  These type of questions come with lots of opinions related to situations, and depends on personal comfort level on the type of data you are dealing with.  For the sake of this question, lets assume it is a simple chat server where users can connect to and chat together.

Example Diagram: [image]

The cluster will be behind a private subnet VPC with elastic-load-balancing directing all connections to these nodes (to and from).  The elastic-load-balancing will be the only direct path to these nodes (there would be no way to connect to a node via name@privatesubnet).

My question is the following:

Based on this question and answer: [Distributed erlang security how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32328314/distributed-erlang-security-how-to)

There are two different types of inner-communication that can take place.  Either, directly connecting nodes using built in functionality, or doing everything over a TCP connection with a custom protocol.  The first is the most easiest, but I believe it comes with a few security issues, and I was wondering based on the above diagram if It would be good enough (Er, okay, Good Enough is not always good when dealing with sensitive information, but there can always be better ways to do everything ...)

How do you secure and Erlang cluster behind a private subnet?  I would like to hide the nodes, and manually connect them, and of course use cookies on them.  Is there any flaws with this approach?  And since a custom protocol using TCP would be the best option, what type of impact does that have on performance?  I want to know the potential security flaws(As I said, there is a lot of mixed information out there on how to do this).

I would be interested in hearing from people who have used Erlang in this manner!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On AWS, with your EC2 nodes in a private subnet, you are pretty safe from unwanted connections to your nodes. You can verify this by trying to connect (in any way) to the machines running your code: if you're using a private subnet you will be unable to do so because the instances are not even addressable outside the subnet.

Your load-balancer should not be forwarding Erlang node traffic.

You can do a little better than the above using some security-group rules. Configure your nodes to use [some range of ports](http://erlang.org/faq/how_do_i.html#idp32796752). Then make a group "erlang" that allows connections to that port range from the "erlang" group and denies the connection otherwise. Finally, assign that security-group to all your Erlang-running instances. This prevents instances that don't need to talk to Erlang from being able to do so.

Comment: When you say: "You can do a little better than the above using some security-group rules." Do you mean keeping the cluster in public facing subnet?  Using the ELB(or possibly Route 53 Private Zone), is to keep the instances in private subnet, is there a better way?  Also, how would you route the traffic back to the connected clients without using the ELB?  Using a NAT Gateway?  Thanks!

Comment: No, keep the private subnet but _add_ SGs. That way if a non-erlang instance in the subnet is compromised it doesn't have access to the cluster. This is something of a corner-case, but it is good discipline IMO. If you need to connect to the cluster for debugging, get on the private subnet (VPN or SSH to jump-box) and allow that private IP access to the "erlang" SG.

Comment: Yes okay!  What did you mean by: "Your load-balancer should not be forwarding Erlang node traffic."  Thank you!  This helps a lot.

Comment: Configuring an ELB, you open ports on the ELB and connect them to a pool of back-end servers. E.g. you might run some web servers on port 9000 and configure ELB port 443 to terminate SSL and forward to port 9000. If you tell EPMD to listen on ports 8000-8500 you should _not_ let the ELB talk to that port range. All external traffic comes via ELB, so if the ELB cannot talk to any port used for clustering then external traffic cannot cluster with you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a very "classic" setup over there.

You aren't going to connect to the cluster from the Internet ― "outside" the ELB. Assuming the "private" sub-net is shared for something else, you can allow only certain IPs (or ranges) to connect via EPMD.

In any case, some machines must be "trusted" to connect to via EPMD and some other(s) can only establish a connection to some other port(s)...otherwise anything that's running your Erlang cluster is useless.

Something to think about is: you might want to (and indeed you will have to) connect to the cluster for doing some "administrative task(s)", either from the Internet or from somewhere else. I've seen this done via SSH; Erlang support that out-of-the-box.

A final word on *doing everything over a TCP connection with a custom protocol*, please don't, you will end-up implementing something on your own that hardly have what Erlang offers, and it's really awesome at. In the end, you'll have the same constraints.

Comment: When you say "you can allow only certain IPs (or ranges) to connect via EPMD."  Do you mean adding in a gateway and restricting access via firewall? (a whitelist)  One of my other thoughts was also something you touched on, Admin Tasks, and also external applications that connect to the cluster and do some actions that normal ELB connections can not do (like retrieving/deleting/verifying sensitive information).  So there also needs to be some IP's that need to be trusted.  It seems like the main concern with Erlang is to disallow users to connect to the nodes directly.